# Alternative to tbb::spin_mutex in standard C++ library?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently refactoring a codebase where tbb::spin_mutex is extensively used. The goal is to eliminate the dependency on TBB (Threading Building Blocks) while maintaining efficient concurrency control. My initial thought was to replace tbb::spin_mutex with std::mutex from the standard C++ library. However, I understand that tbb::spin_mutex offers certain performance advantages, particularly in scenarios where it avoids the overhead of context switching typical in std::mutex.

I'm looking for a standard library alternative to tbb::spin_mutex that would provide similar performance characteristics, especially in terms of efficient handling of short-duration lock contention without the overhead of thread sleeping or context switching.

Is there a recommended approach or a workaround using the C++ standard library (possibly with C++23?) to achieve similar behavior to tbb::spin_mutex? For example, would a custom implementation using std::atomic_flag in a busy-wait loop be advisable, or are there better patterns or practices for this scenario?

Any insights or suggestions for a standard-library-based solution?

Comment: Be aware that spin lock can make codes slower than actual locks (dependent of the target code and target platform). They can even be dangerous and cause deadlocks on some platforms due to a priority inversion (e.g. PS4, PS5, and some real-time systems, so very bad for games). A good example is when a context switch happen during a spin wait, or when a thread able to unlocking the spin lock is never executed because it has a lower priority than the threads doing spin waits. Spin lock are ok when they are guaranteed to last for a small limited fixed time (using fallback to a regular lock).

Comment: Also please note that a CPU core waiting for a spin lock to be released can typically runs at full speed (turbo) at the expense of other core (even with an x86 pause instruction). This has performance and energy consumption impacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would a custom implementation using std::atomic_flag in a busy-wait loop be advisable

Yes, for a *spin mutex*, that's pretty much it and I think a simple implementation could be using a [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) and a `while` loop that goes on until [`test_and_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set) returns `false`.

Example of a basic implementation:

```cpp
class spin_mutex {
public:
    void lock() {
        while (m_f.test_and_set()) {
            // option: sleep for a short duration
        }
    }
    void unlock() { m_f.clear(); }

private:
    std::atomic_flag m_f{false};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cGbGf5jrK)

TBB has a similar construct where they instead of having the `while` loop directly in the `spin_mutex` class, they call `__TBB_LockByte` that contains the `while` loop and in that they call `pause()` which does *"Pause for a while"*.

```cpp
inline __TBB_Flag __TBB_LockByte( __TBB_atomic_flag& flag ) {
    tbb::internal::atomic_backoff backoff;
    while( !__TBB_TryLockByte(flag) ) backoff.pause();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want a microscopic pause in your `spin_mutex`, add a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(`*`short_duration`*`);` in the `while` loop.

---

In C++20, `wait` and `notify*` was added to the `atomic_flag`. This setup outperforms the plain busy loop in my tests by being ~10 times as quick to finish a test with 1000 threads waiting. Not a normal usecase perhaps, but it's good to know that it handles extremes as well as normal cases.

```cpp
class spin_mutex {
public:
    void lock() {
        while(m_f.test_and_set()) m_f.wait(true);
    }
    void unlock() {
        m_f.clear();
        m_f.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag m_f{false};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sEWd8qeEY)

Comment: Note that thread sleep durations might be very coarse (milliseconds, perhaps), whereas busy-waiting is better for delays on the order of a few microseconds. So a trade-off could be to busy-wait for up to some threshold (e.g. your OS thread scheduling resolution) and then use sleep

Comment: *"microscopic pause in your spin_mutex, add [...]"* This is harmful for performance. First, a sleep call can typically do a context switch (and schedule the thread back after a quantum of typically 5-20 ms on mainstream PCs). The OP wants do avoid context switches. Moreover, on Windows, the granularity of a sleep is generally at least 1 ms (if not even few ms, which is huge). This mainly defeat the purpose of a spin lock. On x86-64 there is a pause instruction which is meant to avoid spin lock contention (see `_mm_pause`). It does not really pause the core though.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, I added the sleep option since TBB uses a `__TBB_Yield` in their `pause()`. it's implemented differently on different platforms. `sched_yield()` for Linux and MacOS, `SwitchToThread()` on Windows and standard `std::this_thread::yield()` (which does nothing on my machine) and other variants that seems to actually promote context switching. It's also necessary to yield in one way or another if you have 100 times more threads than processors. I tested it and without yielding it chokes - but sure, for a normal case when you don't have many threads waiting, don't sleep.

Comment: If you have more thread than processor, then a spin lock is a bad idea for performance. Regular lock should be better. This avoid a thread doing a spin wait to steal resources to other threads. The main benefit of spin lock AFAIK to reduce latency, but in such a case it can typically increase the latency (and causes issues -- see my comment below the OP question). System locks can awake the threads waiting for a released lock while a spin lock with a sleep do not (the OS cannot know which thread is waiting).

Comment: Actually, if you have much more threads than processors, it is certainly a good idea not to use system threads but light user thread like fibers. You can then yield the current fiber in the lock. This is still sub-optimal compared to a fiber-aware lock since the fiber scheduler do not know which thread it is better to awake during a yield.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't have 100 times more active threads than processors. I just mentioned it since it's good to have a backup plan in case the spin lock is normally used in situations where only a few threads will be waiting but then in some extreme situations that happens rarely, many threads comes in at the same time, because then the system gets utterly unresponsive- and TBB doesn't seem to be worried about the yielding.

Comment: I have a version of the `spin_lock` which busy waits without yielding if it's the only thread waiting. Other threads coming in afterwards will however sleep for a short time in the loop. This setup don't seem to suffer from any performance dip so perhaps that's one way to do it.

Comment: *"TBB doesn't seem to be worried about the yielding"* Certainly because spin lock are notoriously bad in such a case so it is better not to use it in the first place. The first implementation (so without a sleep) is fine, but it may suffer from contention (especially with there are >1 thread waiting). One can just call `_mm_pause` on x86 CPUs in the loop to reduce this issue (as mentioned in the Intel developers manuals AFAIR). I now this is not standard but I think it is worth mentioning it ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard :) Yeah - In TBBs code they mention that it should be cheap to construct it because of how it's usually used, so it has only a `__TBB_atomic_flag` member (one byte). With my "backup plan" to make it work even if many threads happens to get to the `lock` while another thread has the lock, I made it bigger by adding an `std::atomic<int>` - but it doesn't seem to affect performance in the normal usage _and_ it deals with contention (in my very simple tests). It's clearly not ready for production just yet :-)

Comment: Suoerb answer. Much grategul.